# wso2 bpel appending two or more responses to single output variable?

Tags: xml, response, wso2, bpel

consider i have two responses in XML. i need to append two XML responses and map that appended XML to output variable.

```
response1: <response1>abc</response1> 

response2: <response2>efg</response2>
```

help to append second response to first one and map appended response to output string?

Comment: so you want to have "abcefg" as result? Then `concat($response1, $response2)` is your friend.

Comment: no.. i need response as <response1>abc</response1><response2>efg</response2> as single response.. not concating only data. i need to concat two xml

Comment: @vanto :We are invoking services through while loop and we are getting responses in XML each time. i need all responses in the output in BPEL WSO2

Answer (score 1):

The standard compliant way is to use XSLT and provide a script that appends the second XML to the first. With Apache ODE (and since WSO2 BPS is based on that, I assume it works with that as well), you can either use XQuery or our custom [XPath extensions](http://ode.apache.org/extensions/xpath-extensions.html) like `ode:insert-*`

Comment: can u give a sample or link to proceed what u said?

Comment: We are invoking services through while loop and we are getting responses in XML each time. i need all responses in the output in BPEL WSO2

Comment: You can use any one of the 3 alternatives suggested by vanto. You may find this [1] sample useful to figure out how to use XSLT file inside a BPEL. But the XSLT file has to be implemented by yourself to  suit your requirement. 
[1] - http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.5/products/bps/3.0.0/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/bpel/2.0/TestXslTransform/